# KDE Open recently closed application

Tags: kubuntu, kde

How do I open application, that I have recently closed in Kubuntu ?

**UPD**
It would be great to have keyboard shortcut for this action.

**UPD2**
I mean reopen last closed application, similar to Ctrl+Shift+T in Google Chrome, wich reopens last closed tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the Launcher, and click on Recently Used, you will see your most recently used/closed applications on the top.