# Is there a shortcut to re-open a recently closed program?

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, launcher, programming

I found this [KDE Open recently closed application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463274/kde-open-recently-closed-application) question and it's exactly what I'd like to do, however I am on ubuntu. The only answer on that question is the 'recently used' part of the launcher, but the recently used list doesn't include apps locked to the launcher.

Normally I run most things through the terminal, but things like browsers, I'll run from the launcher. Sometimes I accidentally close them.

**In short**: I'd like the 'ctrl-shift-t' functionality that most browsers have for tabs applied to programs in ubuntu.

If that came in the form of a script, that's fine; I don't really have much experience writing bash scripts, so an explanation or links to docs are appreciated.

Is there a list of recently closed programs stored somewhere on the disk? I know it would probably be the logs, but that would be a hassle to figure out how to parse, I think? I guess I'm hoping there's a nice little log file somewhere that keeps a record of apps closed/opened and the path to the program that runs/starts them. Also: if I wanted ubuntu to create a log file like that, how would I do that?

Comment: Since you mention gui apps, logging windows is most likely what you should do. Is a background script (can be extremely low on juice)  an acceptable option to you?

Comment: Logging windows: does ubuntu do that by default? background script: Yeah, totally. where should I go to figure that out?

Comment: Would you prefer an answer *how* to do it, or an answer + explanation? both can be done :)

Comment: Well, both are completely fine, but I think how/explanation is the priority

Comment: I'll post a concept, maybe you can see if this is enough information. If not, I'll post the code with it.

Comment: Hi Mxt, posted! please mention if it is (not) enough :)

Comment: @Mxt what version of Ubuntu are you using ? Default with Unity desktop ?   If so, it's indeed possible to log open/closed applications there with a simple script and built-in tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As requested in comments, a conceptual answer, no ready-to-use script.*

#### Explanation on concept; how to log the most recently closed application

---

#### Introduction

From a list of processes & pids, it is hard to decide which belongs to an application or another process. Since you mention GUI applications however, we can log *windows*, which gives us all information we need to decide which was the most recently closed application.

#### Using wmctrl to list running GUI applications

[wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) (not on your system by default) is a command- line tool that can give you information on currently existing windows. The command:

```
wmctrl -lp
```

produces a window list, looking like:

```
---
0x02c0000c  0 23772  jacob-System-Product-Name Hud
0x02e0000a -1 23877  jacob-System-Product-Name Desktop
0x0480001d  0 28367  jacob-System-Product-Name Ask Ubuntu General Room | chat.stackexchange.com - Mozilla Firefox
0x05200007  0 26724  jacob-System-Product-Name System Monitor
0x05800084  0 27183  jacob-System-Product-Name *Untitled Document 1 - gedit
---
```

In the second column of the list, you can see the pids of the currently opened windows, like: `23877`, `28367`

From these pids, we can retrieve the process (application) that owns the window, using the command:

```
ps -o cmd= <pid>
```

e.g.:

```
$ ps -o cmd= 27183
gedit
```

Then all we need to do is run a loop with a period of a few seconds, comparing the (unique) list of processes, owning a window (=applications), with the list of a few seconds ago. If a process "left" the list, that's the most recently closed window. In short:

#### (Conceptual) overview of the loop (python style)

```py
applications1 = get_applications()
while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    applications2 = get_applications()
    closed = [app for app in applications1 if not app in applications2]
    if closed:
        most_recent = closed[0]
        # store the process in a file, to be available to run as most recently closed
        open(f, "wt").write(most_recent)
    application1 = application2
```

where f is the path to a file where the most recent application is written to. Subsequently have another process/command start the application in the file and the setup is completed.

#### Language?

No doubt this can be done in pretty much all script languages. To me, python seems just the right one for easily producing scripts like this...

#### Note

Note that the schematic code above is just for example, no tested code!

Comment: Okay, this is pretty neat. I could definitely figure out the rest from here, But while I have your attention, some of the applications I have running link  (output from ps -o cmd=<#>) to a path, some of them just say 'compiz' or list <#>, 'bash' and ps -o cmd=<#> on seperate lines. From the path it should be simple to start the processes, but how would I start them from things like 'compiz' or 'bash'? I'll read up on ps, any other suggested reading?

Comment: @Mxt Some of the "windows" are unlikely to close. Some of these are your desktop, Hud, etc. I usually filter them out first with the help of `XPROP -id` to see if the windows are of type "normal", but since they will not close, in this case, you might just skip that. Procs including paths will also need them when you call them, others will be in `$PATH`. You might run in a few other complications though, which I usually catch using exceptions. When e.g.  repeatedly running any `wmctrl `command, it breaks every n-th occasion (somewhere once per 100-500 times).

Comment: @Mxt P.S. if anywhere in the next few days you can't manage, I'd be happy to post a ready solution afterwards. I appreciate your intention to do it yourself though. If so, please leave a comment. Going to sleep :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help! I've marked your answer as accepted for now, if I can't figure it out, I'll let you know.